# How can I auto-mount my device on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

In the 'Places' menu, I have a drive called 'data'. Everytime I click on it, I get a dialog saying 'Authentication is required to mount the device. an application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. Authenticatio is required to perform this action.'

How can I make ubuntu to auto mount this drive for me everytime I boot up?

Tjh

Comment: Is this a local drive on the machine or a network drive? Also what file system is the drive?

Answer (score 1):

Add the drive to /etc/fstab.  See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/fstab.5.html.

I could give more information if you had given more details about the drive that you want to mount.

Comment: this works for local partitions and network shares.  add `auto` to the option fields to mount at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no "immediate" way to do it, but fortunately you can find different informations on the internet like:

- [Mounting NTFS Partitions](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Karmic#Mounting_NTFS_Partitions_.28with_read.2Fwrite_privileges.29)
- [Mounting Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions/ThirdPartyNTFS3G)

The exact procedure may depend on your linux distribution. I am assuming you are using a recent ubuntu version. Use

```
cat /etc/issue
```

to know your ubuntu release number.

Answer (score 0):

If your stystem has the ability to run scripts during startup, you can run:

```
mountpy
```

Add this to scripts in :

```
System -> Preferences -> Sessions -> Startup Programs
```

This will mount all drives, because IIRC scripts run at startup are done as root.

If you don't have it installed install it with:

```
apt-get install mountpy
```

Comment: you recall right for system boot, but wrong for session startup.  adding this to session startup will run it at X login time under the user's credentials, not root's.

Comment: Can things be run at startup? I'm sure there is a way, perhaps adding it /etc/init/ ?

Comment: ...yeah.  system startup (on ubuntu at least) runs the scripts in `/etc/rcS.d` first, in order, then runs the scripts in `/etc/rcN.d` (where N is the runlevel being started-- generally 2 for standard system boot, or 1 for single-mode boot).  the scripts in those directories are really symlinks, actual scripts live in `/etc/init.d`.  for a run-it-once-at-boot, it'd be better to call the program in the `/etc/rc.local` script than to bother scripting your own init.d script.